# Why great companies have different set of rules for different set of nations?

Tags: company-culture, company-policy

I had worked in an organization for three years and had to quit and stay away for personal issues. After 1.5 years of gap I wanted to start my career over. But this time I had a very hard time explaining my situation and the gap.

Somehow I managed to find a job in *a great* organization. The sad part is that the employer wants me to relocate to a different country. I accepted the offer without any second thought. They started my visa processing and other stuffs. Later, my google search and the advise from my highschool friends who worked in that nation troubled me a lot.

*This famous* company has a completely different set of rules for the employees at that nation. Very rigid. One example: in my nation I need to work 8 hours a day. In that nation I will need to work 10 hours a day. Here it is two week notice, there it is 3 months notice. The list just goes on and on.

I don't know how I can reject the offer at this time. This HR may blacklist me if I deny it at the last minute.

I really wonder why the same company has a different set of rigid rules for different set of nations.

Why this happens only to me

Comment: err companies have to follow the laws relating to employment law's. Some NGO's can avoid some of them

Comment: Which country are you going from to? two weeks seems to indicate going from the USA

Answer (score 7):

Ask your company whether you will be working under your nation's rules with respect to working hours or the other nation's. Since you will be an expat in that other nation, ask whether you will be getting any expat benefits from working there.

Determine ASAP whether your new working conditions are acceptable to you. If not, pull out all the stops to get another job - it's a lot easier for you to find yourself another job and here and now in your country than to try finding a job in your country when you are stuck in the other country.

"Why this happens to me" is what happens to those who say "yes" first and check later for gotchas :) Nothing personal.

Comment: My friends who worked in this company told me that the managers there will expect me to follow their rules no matter what. You are right. I should not have been so desperate to find a job. Great companies are not the great at all nations.

Answer (score 7):

> I really wonder why the same company has a different set of rigid
>   rules for different set of nations.

Nations themselves have rules (laws) within which companies must operate. What is legal in one nation might not be legal in another.

Additionally, locales have their own norms. What is typical in one locale might not be typical in another. What is necessary to attract and keep a pool of talent in one locale could be insufficient in another.

In your instance, one locale might permit and expect workers to spend 10 hours per day on the job, while another might prohibit it entirely.

> Why this happens only to me

I'm sure you know this doesn't happen only to you. It happens to anyone who chooses to move to another locale. Even within some larger nations the norms are different in different parts of the country. Moving requires that you adjust to local norms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know *why* any differences exist, you'll have to ask your employer. There may be legal restrictions. Beyond that, each company has to make its own decisions about how much they follow local practices versus establishing their own practices as much as possible across the entire company.

(Reminder: The question as posed was indeed "why", not "what" or "how can I get an exception made" or "will rejecting the offer at the last minute hurt me". If you want answers to those, make them questions rather than statements.)

Comment: In my experience, most of the rules are pretty freely available and companies are used to getting and responding to this sort of question. Admittedly, I work for a world-class employer. But the fact is that only they can begin to answer why they made the decisions they made; all ANYONE else can do is point at external influences and guess. They may not give you the whole truth, but I would bet they'll at least give your their standard public statement on the matter, which may be close to the whole truth. I know that isn't the answer you want to hear, but it's only one that's actually correct.

Comment: BTW, the unasked question: Almost nobody will blacklist an applicant for rejecting a job offer. They're very aware that it is only an offer, and that you may have other offers. "Sorry, I got a better offer so I'm not interested on those terms at this time", optionally accompanied by "here's what it would take to make me interested again", is an ENTIRELY reasonable and normal response. If you don't like the offer, don't take it.